# Multiply each element in a vector by itself to create a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply each element in a vector by itself such that it produces a matrix that is symmetric about the diagonal. For example, given this vector::

```
x <- 1:3
```

I would like to create this:

```
1 2 3  
2 4 6 
3 6 9
```

i.e:

```
x[1]*x[1] x[2]*x[1] x[3]*x[1]  
x[1]*x[2] x[2]*x[2] x[3]*x[2] 
x[1]*x[3] x[2]*x[3] x[3]*x[3]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
x %o% x
```

which is a shortcut for

```
outer(x, x)
```

You can also do

```
 tcrossprod(x)
```